# Using doT.js with require.js

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I'm using  an authentication example from here https://github.com/alexanderscott/backbone-login and instead of using underscore templates I would like to use doT.js templates.

I've added the doT.js source to the lib directory and my config.js looks like this

```
if (typeof DEBUG === 'undefined') DEBUG = true;

require.config({

    baseUrl: '/assets',

    paths: {

        //'jquery'            : 'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js',
        'jquery'              : 'assets/lib/jquery',
        'underscore'            : 'assets/lib/underscore',         // load lodash instead of underscore (faster + bugfixes)

        'backbone'              : 'assets/lib/backbone',
        'bootstrap'             : 'assets/vendor/bootstrap/js/bootstrap',
        'doT'                   : 'assets/lib/doT',
        'text'                  : 'assets/lib/text',
        'parsley'               : 'assets/lib/parsley'

    },

    // non-AMD lib
    shim: {
        //'jquery'                : { exports  : '$' },
        'underscore'            : { exports  : '_' },
        'backbone'              : { deps : ['underscore', 'jquery'], exports : 'Backbone' },
        'bootstrap'             : { deps : ['jquery'], exports : 'Bootstrap' },
        'parsley'               : { deps: ['jquery'] },
        'doT'                   : { exports : 'doT'}

    }

});

require(['main']);           // Initialize the application with the main application file.
```

my app.js looks like this

```
define([
    "jquery",
    "underscore",
    "backbone",
    "doT",
    "utils"

],
function($, _, Backbone, doT) {

    var app = {
        root : "/",                     // The root path to run the application through.
        URL : "/",                      // Base application URL
        API : "/api",                   // Base API URL (used by models & collections)

        // Show alert classes and hide after specified timeout
        showAlert: function(title, text, klass) {
            $("#header-alert").removeClass("alert-error alert-warning alert-success alert-info");
            $("#header-alert").addClass(klass);
            $("#header-alert").html('<button class="close" data-dismiss="alert">×</button><strong>' + title + '</strong> ' + text);
            $("#header-alert").show('fast');
            setTimeout(function() {
                $("#header-alert").hide();
            }, 7000 );
        }
    };

    $.ajaxSetup({ cache: false });          // force ajax call on all browsers

    //alert(doT.template("what up {{=it.name}}"),{'name': 'John'});
    // Global event aggregator
    app.eventAggregator = _.extend({}, Backbone.Events);

    return app;

});
```

and HeaderView.js looks like this

```
define([
    "app",
    "text!templates/header.html",
    "utils",
    "bootstrap"
], function(app, HeaderTpl){

    var HeaderView = Backbone.View.extend({

        template: doT.template(HeaderTpl), //_.template(HeaderTpl),

        initialize: function () {
            _.bindAll(this);

            // Listen for session logged_in state changes and re-render
            app.session.on("change:logged_in", this.onLoginStatusChange);
        },

        events: {
            "click #logout-link" : "onLogoutClick",
            "click #remove-account-link" : "onRemoveAccountClick"
        },

        onLoginStatusChange: function(evt){
            this.render();
            if(app.session.get("logged_in")) app.showAlert("Success!", "Logged in as "+app.session.user.get("username"), "alert-success");
            else app.showAlert("See ya!", "Logged out successfully", "alert-success");
        },

        onLogoutClick: function(evt) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            app.session.logout({});  // No callbacks needed b/c of session event listening
        },

        onRemoveAccountClick: function(evt){
            evt.preventDefault();
            app.session.removeAccount({});
        },


        render: function () {
            if(DEBUG) console.log("RENDER::", app.session.user.toJSON(), app.session.toJSON());
            this.$el.html(this.template({ 
                logged_in: app.session.get("logged_in"),
                user: app.session.user.toJSON() 
            }));
            return this;
        },

    });

    return HeaderView;
});
```

when i load the page I get the error

> Uncaught ReferenceError: doT is not defined

I can call the doT.template() function in the app.js file and I can see that doT.js is loaded in my network tab but when I try and use it in the HeaderView.js I keep getting the error.  I am new to require.js so I'm sure I'm misunderstanding how it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the source of [doT](https://github.com/olado/doT/blob/master/doT.js) I see that it calls `define` by itself. So you do not need a `shim` configuration for it. Providing a `shim` for a module that calls `define` can confuse RequireJS.

Moreover, in the case at hand here, I see that if doT detects that it is an AMD environment (which RequireJS is), then it does **not** define itself in the global space as `doT`. So your `HeaderView.js` file will have to have doT among the required modules. Something like:

```
define([
    "app",
    "text!templates/header.html",
    "doT",
    "utils",
    "bootstrap"
], function(app, HeaderTpl, doT){
```

Comment: This worked.  I removed the shim and added doT to the define and function and it renders. How did you know that doT detects if it's in an AMD environment?  Does it say in the documentation or is it in the code somewhere?  Is this the proper way to go about building my web application defining doT only in the places where I need it?

Comment: Checking is quite simple. What you do is search for `define(` in the source code. If you find it, there's a great chance that the module is AMD-aware. However, it could be that it is just a `define(` function that has nothing to do with AMD. So you check just before the `define(` call for code that tests that `define` is a function and that `define.amd` is a truthy value, because this is the way to detect that you're running in an AMD-compatible environment.